# Can child workflows, in MS Dynamics CRM 4, be used as standalone workflows?

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-4

I was curious - can a child workflow only be called by another workflow or can it also be used as a standalone workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Crm 4.0, if you mark a workflow as a *Child Workflow* it can be called from within other workflow as a sub process that's run asynchronously. It can also be ran as a standalone workflow in it's own right.

The tickbox is additive in that it just means the workflow can also be ran as a child process.